# subsequence of unitary matrices has two limit

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence of unitary matrices $U_k=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \end{array} 
\right)^k,k=1,2,\dots$

I am not able  to show that there are two possible limits of subsequences

Could anyone help me how?

Comment: What are $U_2, U_3$?

Comment: Alternatively you can diagonalize $U_1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Calculate a few powers of $U$ to see what’s happening:

$$\begin{align*}
U^1&=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\\
U^2&=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\\
U^3&=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}U^2=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}=U\\
U^4&=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}U^3=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}=U^2=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
\end{align*}$$

This looks a lot like what happens with the real sequence $\langle(-1)^n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, which has a subsequence converging to $1$ and another converging to $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Compute $U_k$ explicitly for the first few $k$-values. Seeing the pattern?